# Unable to remove Expo Location.watchPositionAsync()

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I wanted to be able to track user locations for some features in my application, but I want users to be able to turn off location if they want. I've been using `expo-location` to find the users location, request permission and varies other things. But when I use watchPositionAsync, I can't remove it when the user turns it off the feature. I read the docs and it said that I could use remove() but I get the following error when  I try to do that:

`Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: client.location.remove is not a function. (In 'client.location.remove()', 'client.location.remove' is undefined)`

For reference client is just a global object which stores some settings for the user (It's so I don't have to keep fetching it over and over again).

client.js

```js
let client = {
   user: {},
   location: null
};
```

tracking.js

```js
import * as Location from 'expo-location';

export async function startTracking(client){
    console.log('Starting tracking')
    if(!client.location){
        client.location = Location.watchPositionAsync({
            accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Highest,
            distanceInterval: 1,
            timeInterval: 5000,
        }, (loc) => {
            console.log(loc)
        });
    }
}


export async function stopTracking(client){
    console.log('Remove tracking')
    await client.location.remove();
}
```

More information:

- Expo version - 40.0.1
- Android version - Oxygen OS 10.5.11
- React native version - 0.63.4
- expo-location version - 10.0.0
- Client.js has a better structure than the one above...

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having a similar problem

Comment: No I didn't find a solution for this, I ended up using current position and checking that x seconds instead of using watching for position.

Comment: I managed to use watchposition to track location, but I still don't know how to remove it

Comment: Yeah I've managed to use watchposition but I wasn't able to remove it. From what I've searched client.location.remove() should have worked but for some reason it didn't which I was confused about. If you want I can try bounty this question and see if someone will provide an answer :)

Comment: That would be good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not waiting the returned object by the function watchPositionAsync.

> Returns a **promise** resolving to a subscription object, which has one field

I take this [source](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/location/).

Try this code.

```js
import * as Location from 'expo-location';

export async function startTracking(client){
    console.log('Starting tracking')
    if(!client.location){
        client.location = await Location.watchPositionAsync({
            accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Highest,
            distanceInterval: 1,
            timeInterval: 5000,
        }, (loc) => {
            console.log(loc)
        });
    }
}


export async function stopTracking(client){
    console.log('Remove tracking')
    await client.location.remove();
}
```

Comment: Sorry to interrupt but I have a question too. If I use states, like below: https://pastebin.com/F7wtnH2m
Is this the same, is it good this way?

Comment: I can only say that this code work. Can you tell me how would you like to use this code? Add a [cleanup](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup) to remove the tracking when you unmount your component.

Comment: I have a state (tourStarted) which represents a button click( on button click I set the tourStarted true). When the tourStarted is true in the useEffect I want to start monitoring the users location with watchPositionAsync. And when I click on another button to stop the tour I want to interrupt the users position tracking (remove the watchPositionAsync()). I hope I was clear. I tried with a cleanup function, like this: https://pastebin.com/p8gKXTEN

I asked this question on the expo github, and got a response and they closed it. The response is in the pastebin, but I didn't understand it.

Comment: Do you want the geolocation to be available within application or only do a temporary tracking in a specific screen in a specific component? Can you give me the link to your github question? From what I understand from the answer, they tell you that when you use 'setWatchId' outside of your useEffect you will not run the code inside your useEffect because the useEffect only watch 'tourStarted' changement. They tell you that you can change your code too take this factor in consideration.

Comment: You need to remove the first if in your cleanup function because it will be called only when the component will unmount. This function needs to remove the tracking of the user in the case the user is tracked but is leaving you component. Without it, the user will still tracked, but you cannot cancel it anymore because you lost the value of 'watchId.'

Comment: My whole app works on the user location. I'm using google maps, and navigating the user. I only use setWatchId in the usEffect, I don't use it anywhere else. I will try to remove the first if. This was the only answer on github, they closed the issue. I copied the whole question in the pastebin (what I earlier sent)

Comment: You can use this code for the geolocation, but there will be some limitation. You need to use this code in the component where you use the tracking. You need to use the useEffect to change the value 'watchId'.

Comment: Thank you. In The meantime I found a live example on expo snack: https://snack.expo.io/@chronsyn/watchpositionasync-example

Comment: @TylerJoe THANK YOU! Your answer should be marked as THE right solution.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward and more generic implementation as a hook:

```js
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export const useUserLocation = () => {
  const [userLocation, setUserLocation] = useState<Location.LocationObjectCoords | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    let subscription: Location.LocationSubscription | null = null;

    (async () => {
      const { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status === 'granted') {
        subscription = await Location.watchPositionAsync(
          { accuracy: Location.Accuracy.BestForNavigation },
          ({ coords }) => setUserLocation(coords),
        );
      } else {
        console.log('Location permissions not granted');
      }
    })();

    return () => {
      subscription?.remove();
    };
  }, []);

  return userLocation;
};
```